# How do I set the package name that OpenAI uses to generate the README using the typescript generator?

Tags: typescript, openapi, openapi-generator, perplexity

I created an [SDK](https://github.com/rgomezp/perplexity-sdk) for Perplexity.ai using OpenAI and the generated README does not include the package name.

I didn't see a setting for it in the Typescript generator settings.

I ran the generator and was expecting the documentation in the README to use the package name?

The class that is generated is `DefaultApi` and but the final package should just be `Perplexity`.

I would expect the code example to show something like:

`Perplexity.apiFunction()`

But it just shows:

`.apiFunction()`

Comment: Hey :) Could you add some detail on how you're using OpenAI to generate the SDK?